# Load reactApexChart candlestick data from api

Tags: reactjs, charts

I am getting data as props. These porps are returning array. I want to make a stock data chart. In filteredData I am getting day open, close, high, low value. In dateTimeArray I am getting the date. I want to pass this array to the candlestick chart. How can I do that.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts'


const Echart = ({filteredData, dateTimeArray, valumesData}) => {


const [series, setSeries] = useState({series: [{
   data: [{
      x: dateTimeArray,
      y: filteredData
    }]
  }]})


const [options, setOptions] = useState({
options: {
  chart: {
    type: 'candlestick',
    height: 350
  },
  title: {
    text: 'CandleStick Chart',
    align: 'left'
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yaxis: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}})


return (
    <div>
         <ReactApexChart  options={options} series={series} type='candlestick' width={800} 
         height={500} />
    </div>
)
}
export default Echart
```